# Trace Listener and Console Output not matching up in XML reader

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have a very hard-coded XML reader below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace XML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        // XML text reader stuff
            XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader("H:\\User\\Desktop\\secLendingXML.cfm.xml");
        //string[] Fed_Array = new string[] {"Actual Available to Borrow", "Outstanding Loans",
        //"Par Submitted", "Par Accepted", "WTD Average Rate"};
        int j = 0;
    // Trace listener stuff.
        Stream myFile = File.Create("H:\\User\\Desktop\\Fed_Sec_Lending.txt");
        TextWriterTraceListener myTextListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(myFile);
        Trace.Listeners.Add(myTextListener);
        while (textReader.Read())
        {
            switch (textReader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    for (int i = 0; i < textReader.AttributeCount; i++)
                    {
                        textReader.MoveToAttribute(i);
                        switch (textReader.Name)
                        {
                            case "securityMaturityDate": 
                                Trace.Write(textReader.Value + ",");
                                Console.Write(textReader.Value + ",");
                                break;
                            case "couponRate":
                                Trace.Write(textReader.Value + ",");
                                Console.Write(textReader.Value + ",");
                                break;
                            case "securityType":
                                Trace.Write(textReader.Value + ",");
                                Console.Write(textReader.Value + ",");
                                j = 0;
                                break;
                            case "value":
                                Trace.Write(textReader.Value + ",");
                                Console.Write(textReader.Value + ",");
                                j = j + 1;
                                if (j > 4)
                                {
                                    Trace.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                                    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                                }
                                break;

                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to be working fine for the most part in reading [this](http://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/seclend/xml/v3_0/secLendingXML.cfm) XML page from my desktop.  However, the Trace writer does not seem to be writing the same data as the console output.  I have a snapshot of the console output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECtgG.png), and the bottom of the text file that the Trace is writing to [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59ewj.png), and as you can see, the last few rows don't match up.

For whatever reason, the text file is not receiving the same output as the console, even though they should be.  Is there a reason anyone can see as to why the text file is being cut short here?

Comment: It looks like `Trace` and `Console` are each getting every other entry.  I'm not sure why, but you could try storing textReader.Value to a local variable within your cases and then writing that to `Trace` and `Console`.

Comment: @JonSenchyna. Okay, I'll give that a try and then report back in a few minutes.

Comment: I think it should work, but I can't tell you why, as `XmlTextReader.Value` should not be changing the position of your `XmlTextReader` as far as I know.

Comment: @JonSenchyna. Unfortunately, that didn't work.  Do you have any other ideas as to what could be going on?  I'm still missing the last 4 rows of output in my text file.

Comment: Have you tried to flush the buffer? `myTextListener.Flush()`

Comment: @ScottieMc.  Yeah, still a no-go.  I've also tried adding break points and seeing where it stops writing to the text file.  It continues in the console, and just doesn't in the text file.  No errors, warnings, or anything.  Just goes over the line without writing anything.

Comment: The only other thing I can think to try would be to make sure you properly dispose of your FileStream when you're finished processing. Maybe something is hung up in a buffer there.

Comment: @ScottieMc.  Yeah, just tried that too.  No luck.  Oh well, I'll ask a few devs downstairs to take a look at it and see if they can spot anything - I was hoping I wouldn't have to waste their time.  Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer the question by replacing the Trace writer with a Streamwriter.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("H:\\myName\\Desktop\\Fed_Sec_Lending.txt"))
```

i.e.

```
string textvalmatd = textReader.Value;
writer.Write(textvalmatd + ",");
```

for everything where:

```
Trace.Write(textvalmatd + ",");
```

would have been.

Thanks for the help for the few people that commented.